# Data Updates On View Only In Refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

In one `HTML` page I have two views. One to get data and one to display the stored data. I set condition to add button to add data and switch to display view. Problem is data is getting stored and view switching but I can't able to view the stored data. `If I refresh, then the data is displaying.` I share my code here, tell me where I am going.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="ifAdd">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fname" name="fname">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="lname" name="lname">
</div>

<div *ngIf="ifDisplay">
<div *ngFor="let name of names">
<h1>{{name.fname}}</h1>
<h1>{{name.lname}}</h1>
</div>
</div>
<button type="button"type="submit" (click)="add() ">Save</button>
```

**TS**

```
  ifAdd:Boolean = true;
    ifDisplay:Boolean;
    public fname;
    public lname;
    names = [];
    ngOnint() {
        this.get();
    }

    add() {
        var data = {
            fname: this.fname,
            lname: this.lname
        }
        this.addService.add(data).subscribe(res => this.names.push(res));
       this.ifAdd= false;
       this.ifDisplay= true; 
       //I have to use window.location.reload() here to get the data displayed. I don't want to do that

    }
    }

    get() {
        this.getService.get().subscribe(res => this.names.push(res));

    }
```

With the above code I can able to add data to db, retrieve and switch view but data display in that view only after refresh that's a issue.

Comment: post the other view

Comment: check html code `<*ngIf=ifAdd>`  and `<*ngIf=ifDisplay>` those are the two views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make get request when data is being saved like this -

```
this.addService.add(data).subscribe(res => {
   this.names.push(res));
   this.ifAdd= false;
   this.ifDisplay= true;
   this.get();
});
```

TIP: Also you can avoid using two variables instead, toggle single one.

```
get() {
    this.getService.get().subscribe(res => {this.names = res});

}
```

Comment: I tried this. I am getting duplication of data. If add `xy` and `ab` , then I add `bc`. I am getting `xy,ab,bc,xy,ab,bc`.

Comment: check my update, this is happening because array is not getting getting reset